# Stripe payment_intent is null but subscription succedes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using nodejs and reactjs to make payments with stripe.
A user fills fields like name, address etc. And then of course fields for credit card details.
React does a few calls:

```
const createdCustomer = await createCustomer("someUserInfoObject");
if(!createdCustomer.success){
    alert("createdCustomer failed");
}
const createdSubscription = await createSubscription("somePriceId", createdCustomer.newlyCreatedId);
if(!createdSubscription.success){
    alert("createdSubscription failed");
}
...more code to finalize payment
```

On backend, nodejs execute calls to stripe API:

```
const createCustomer = async function(req, res) {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create(someUserInfo);
    return res.json({message: "createCustomer",customer: customer,success: true});
}
const createSubscription = async function(req, res) {
    const options = {
        customer: req.body.newlyCreatedId,
        items: [{price: req.body.price_id}],
        payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
        expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
    }
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create(options);
    if(
    !subscription || !subscription.latest_invoice || !subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent || !subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret){
        return res.json({error: "no_payment_intent",success: false});
    }
}
```

This code always adds a new entry in subscriptions, when I check in stripe dashboard.
So basically it works.
But in the nodejs code above, when calling:

```
stripe.subscriptions.create
```

It happens often that the last if statement fails. The reason is that

```
subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent
```

becomes null. Why? All the other fields that I print in the console seem ok. But the payment intent is null sometimes. For some reason, I need to "subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret" and store it in my db. But when payment_intent is null I cannot get it and Im forced to show error like if the payment failed. But it didn't fail, according to the new subscription created in stripe dashboard.

Comment: Is it possible you're using a $0 price, which wouldn't require a payment?

Comment: Yes, you are right. When it fails it is because it is doing a 0 amount payment. But why is it doing that?
I printed out the response from subscription, and in both case it is using the same price_id product.
The failing transaction has "latest_invoice.amount_due = 0" while the one that works has "latest_invoice.amount_due = 300". The failing one has "payment_intent = null" while the other is an object.
I compared output for both transactions and there are very few differences. One  is "pending_setup_intent" which is null one it works, but has a "seti_ID" when it fails.

Comment: Why is this strange thing happening? As I said, both transactions have the same price ID, which has amount = 300. The field "plan" looks exactly the same for both. Another difference is "status = active" when it fails and "status = incomplete" when it works.

Comment: This happens because for free plans no payment is needed, the subscription can be started right away. Payments below the minimum charge amount are similar, but will eventually need a payment instrument. If this behaves inconsistently for the same price you might want to contact support to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problem was related to the minimum amount. I had a plan which was 1 SEK. The minimum amount is 1 SEK (something similar with dollars).

Comment: Are you saying that for the same 1 SEK plan this sometimes leads to a payment and sometimes not? Make sure you use a new customer. If you reuse a customer, you'll find want happens is the amount below the minimum goes to an owing balance, and would apply to future invoice payments for that customer. For testing this kind of behaviour it's best to use a new customer unless you specifically want to test how it works for an existing customer.